# Bash fail if any single command fails but still run all commands

Tags: bash

Probably a simple question but an elegant solution is not coming to mind.  I would like to run a series of commands (each one is a test) and return 1 if any of them returned non-zero.  Typically I would do something like:

```
thingA && thingB && thingC
exit $?
```

However, that won't run thingC if thingB fails and I want to ensure that all 3 run.  I can easily think of an inelegant approach:

```
final_result=0
retval=thingA
if [[ $retval != 0 ]] then
  final_result=1
fi
retval=thingB
...
exit $final_result
```

Is there some simple, elegant way to get what I want?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this elegant enough?

```
status=0
thingA || status=1
thingB || status=1
thingC || status=1
exit $status
```

You can use `$?` instead of `1` if you prefer.  Or you could identify the last command that failed by using statuses 1, 2, 3 when you do the assignment.  If you wanted to know the first command that failed, you'd have to test `$status` before assigning to it.